# Fastest way to load images from WCF service to WP7 app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am fetching bulk images from my WCF web service to my WP7 App which is extremely slow. My App fetches all the images first and then it displays the images. I want to gradually fill up my listbox with images which is loaded first and do not wait for all the images to fetch at one time. 
I am getting the images(in the form of bytes) and its title in a List. Can somebody tell me the fastest way to load the images in app?

Comment: install a static image server on your iis. dont use software if you need speed

Comment: @jacklondon I have no idea about this static image server. Can you please explain how to install it on IIS?

Comment: create default web site in iis, give a host name like 'static.foo.com' then fetch your images from that url.

Comment: @jacklondon Ok, then it's like getting the images from a folder through web site for example: static.foo.com/Folder/image.jpg. So I have to create the image folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\Folder.